# Simple php calculator error (new to this!)

Tags: php

When I say 'new', I mean that this is just about the first time I'm attempting php.

Anyway. I keep getting this error notice "Undefined index: type in c:\x\calculator.php on line 33", but it still echoes "You forgot to pick mathtype!" and the calculator works fine. This error notice occurs only when I don't select any radio box for math type (+-/*).

```
//Part of the form
<form action="calculator.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="1stnumber">
<input type="text" name="2ndnumber">
<input type="radio" name="type" value="addition">
<input type="radio" name="type" value="subtraction">
<input type="submit" name="send">

<?php
//My variables
$number = $_POST['1stnumber']
$numbero = $_POST['2ndnumber']
$mathtype = $_POST['type'] /* **<-line 33** */

//The calculation part of the form here, which is working

//Tell the user if he didn't pick a math type (+-)
if(is_null($mathtype)){
  echo "You forgot to pick mathtype!"
  }
?>
```

Tried with elseif as well.. I don't see what's wrong between line 33 and the if(is_null()) line!

Sorry if it looks poor, messy, or if something doesn't make sense. Might be a few typos as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try to check isset($mathtype)

Comment: Did you remember to wrap the entire page in `<html> .. </html>` tags?

Comment: When you're asking other people to put in the time to help you, instead of apologizing for messy formatting or typos, take the time to actually correct these things yourself.

Comment: @warren `html` `body` `head` tags can be omitted in html

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes and radio buttons are not posted to the server, so you should check if the "type" index is even set before trying to read it out.

Comment: Please take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Comment: @CaseyRule It's quite a long form, and I don't have internet access on the computer I have the form on, so I did it all by hand. I do not know how to not make it look messy either.

Comment: @warren I'm new to php, but not that new to html. It's correctly wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if type is posted before you pick it up

```
if(isset($_POST['type']))
{
   $mathtype = $_POST['type'];
}
else
{
    echo "Type was not selected";
}
```

Comment: Should this be right after my variables?

Comment: "Simply check if type is posted before you pick it up"

Would that mean that it'd first see if a box is checked, and then run the rest/just return if one isn't? Finding it hard to make sense of it all!

Answer (score 1):

Set a default selected option, using the `checked` attribute.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="type" value="addition" checked="checked"> +</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="type" value="subtraction"> -</label>
```

Don't forget inputs needs labels in html if left out you can use a `placeholder` attribute, but that's clearly not possible with `type="radio"`; therefore wrap the `input` in a `label` with the text description next to it eg + or -

Also, is this a copy and paste error, bc all php statements must be terminated with a semicolon `;`

```
$number = $_POST['1stnumber'];       // <- terminate
$numbero = $_POST['2ndnumber'];      // <- terminate
$mathtype = $_POST['type'];          // <- terminate

echo "You forgot to pick mathtype!"; // <- terminate
```

Comment: `selected="selected"`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky many ways to do it (`selected`, `selected='selected'`, `selected=""`), but for exactness i changed it...

Comment: Ok :) Shouldn't that be `checked`, instead of `selected`, btw for radio buttons ? :P

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yes lol what an egregious mistake

Answer (score 0):

Check if the form is posted:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    //My variables
    $number = $_POST['1stnumber']
    $numbero = $_POST['2ndnumber']
    $mathtype = $_POST['type'] /* **<-line 33** */

    //The calculation part of the form here, which is working

    //Tell the user if he didn't pick a math type (+-)
    if(is_null($mathtype)){
      echo "You forgot to pick mathtype!"
      }
}
?>
```

Else the is_null check will also be executed on the first load (before the form has been posted).

Comment: The form can be posted without posting the `type` variable "when I don't select any radio box for math type". Also, `$_POST['method']` will be undefined.

Comment: Yes of course further validation still has to be done.

Comment: @Peter That gave me another error notice! :(

Comment: @Jimmy Oops, typo, fixed it

Comment: Thanks Peter, I think I got it!

Answer (score 0):

It's always good practice to check if the variable you're trying to retrieve from $_POST has actually been set, try this:

```
<?php
    //My variables
    if (isset($_POST['1stnumber'])) {
        $number = $_POST['1stnumber'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['2ndnumber'])) {
        $numbero = $_POST['2ndnumber'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
        $mathtype = $_POST['type']; /* **<-line 33** */
    }

    //The calculation part of the form here, which is working

    //Tell the user if he didn't pick a math type (+-)
    if (is_null($mathtype)) {
        echo "You forgot to pick mathtype!";
    }
?>
```